# How to add an image in crystal reports when a parameter is met

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am attempting to add an approval signature to a crystal report. The approver is not always the same person, so the signature will change based on who approved it.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the images in report and write supress condition for each image according to the selection of parameter.

For xyz image add supress condition as

E.g

```
if parameter = 'xyz'
then false
else true
```

Comment: I added the suppress condition to no avail.

if {appoved_by_staff} = 'jsmith'
then true
else false

Comment: what condition did you add, can you add image?

Comment: I added an image, I right clicked on the image and clicked format image. I then clicked on the X+2 and added if {appoved_by_staff} = 'jsmith' then true else false

Comment: is `{appoved_by_staff}` is a parameter and `{appoved_by_staff}` exactly has `jsmith` and you need to add false when conditon is meet and true when condition is no meet. Editing the answer

Comment: Yes, {appoved_by_staff} is the parameter and the image should show when {appoved_by_staff} = jsmith. I am unsure what you mean by false when condition

Comment: True and false will tell crystal to either hide or show the image according to the condition

Answer (score 0):

You can insert just one image.
Right-click it and select Format Graphic
In the picture tab, enter a dynamic expression (IF THEN ELSE  or SELECT CASE) for the   Graphic Location property.

Comment: When adding an if then else statement in the graphic location it gives an error a string is required here.

Comment: Each of the results returned by that expression must be a path to an image file.